# Ionic 2: link to video file

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying out Ionic 2 for the first time.
I'm having one issue, though. I can't figure out where to put a video file I need to link to.

I'm using a plugin ([cordova-vr-player](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player)) to use VR view.

At some point, on `home.ts`, I put `GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo('shark.mp4');`
This opens the player, but then I get the error (on android):

`Error loading video: com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: shark.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).`

I've put `shark.mp4` in the same folder as `home.ts`.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maker of the plugin, [jleszczynski](https://github.com/jleszczynski), was kind enough to [help](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player/issues/2) me out:

`var path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/video.mp4';
GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo(path);`

Required: `cordova-plugin-file`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Looks like I was wrong! Correct answer [here](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player/issues/2)

---

When compiled the app will read from the root of the www folder.

What I would recommend is setting a folder structure and moving the video like - www/assets/video/shark.mp4

Then in your code you can reference the video like so:

GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo('assets/video/shark.mp4')

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The player keeps saying the file isn't there.